# Query to retrieve data based on many composite keys

Tags: sql, database, informix

Unfortunately the db I am stuck supporting contains little to no surrogate/primary keys, and there's no chance to add one.  So I'm left with using composite keys.

I'd like to query a single table with a list of composite keys.  I can have as many as 5k composite keys.  So how can I do this?  The below query works, but I would have to build it dynamically and is not something I've ever seen done or had to do.  It seems there should be a better way to do this...

```
select * from dog_manners
where 
col1 NOT IN ('', 'abcd')
and
(
    -- here are the composite keys (each pair must be unique)
    (col2 = 'Scottish Terrier' and col3 = 'black') or
    (col2 = 'Golden Retriever' and col3 = 'brown') or
    (col2 = 'Golden Retriever' and col3 = 'wheaten') or
    (col2 = 'Yorkshire Terrier' and col3 = 'brown') or
    etc...
)
```

If this is the best way, is there a limit to the number of OR conditions I can have?  If so, I'll have to break it up into smaller chuncks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know informix so I googled and it appears as if temporary tables exists. One idea is to create one and use that in a join:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp1 ( col2 varchar(20), col3 varchar(20) );
INSERT INTO tmp1 (col2, col3) VALUES ('Scottish Terrier', 'black')
                                   , ('Golden Retriever', 'brown');
SELECT * 
FROM dog_manners x
JOIN tmp1
    ON tmp1.col2 = x.col2
   AND tmp1.col3 = x.col3;
```

Comment: The temp table solution gave me an idea to join to another already existing table based on filter data I had for the other table.  Basically I execute the same query twice but modify the second query to join to the other table.  It takes 2 queries but works efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'd recommend this, but without more detail to understand your requirement

> but needs to be built dynamically

the following alternative would work, although may not be terribly efficient:

```
select * from dog_manners
where 
col1 NOT IN ('', 'abcd')
and TRIM(col2)||':'||TRIM(col3) IN 
(
    'Scottish Terrier:black', 'Golden Retriever:brown',
    'Golden Retriever:wheaten', 'Yorkshire Terrier:brown',
    ...
)
```

Can you give some more detail on how these combinations are generated?

Comment: I changed the wording in my question to make it clearer.  Your solution is pretty much the same as my solution using the OR statements only you're combining the composite key into 1.  The dog breads and colors are system generated (not user generated), so your concatenated keys would be unique.